# Pentaho_ce_5.0_Saiku Analytics_Cube_SQLException

Tags: postgresql, visualization, pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I created my cube olap in PSW and I have published in into Pentaho ce 5.0 successfully.

Now , I creat a new Saiki Analytics in order to display the dimensions and measure ,, But I have the following error :

https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10380316_273476419498280_2061511225924222439_n.jpg

I tried the query in PostgreSQL and it work fine .. I don't know what is the problem there !!

How can I fix it !?

Comment: if your cube is published and the same thing you want to visualize using saiku then you have to open saiku and select the cube and then you can visualize by selecting dimensions and measures.

So may be you are missing something , check your flow 1 time..

Comment: I checked my flow.. the error is disappeared, and now Saiku display nothing when I use drill through on cell.
I don't know what is the problem :s !!!

Answer (score 0):

- I restarted Pentaho , and that error above is disappeared. 
  I created new analysis using Saiku. But when I used drill through on cell, it always returned empty result without any error message !!!

https://scontent-a-mad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/t1.0-9/10330452_273674162811839_9200273505653656022_n.jpg